# How to integrate push services from AWS Mobile Hub sample project in an existing android project?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, aws-mobilehub

I have created an android sample project using AWS Mobile Hub with User Sign-In and Push Notifications services.

I've downloaded the project and opened it through Android Studio, in order to take the necessary files for push notifications from the sample project and to integrate it in my existing Android app.

I thought it would be simple, but then I found out this huge files branch:

[image: AWS Mobile Hub Sample Project - 'src' Folder File Branch]

It is difficult to understand what files I do need and what files I don't need. Could you please help me to figure out what do I need to import into my existing project in order to integrate Push Notifications in my app?

Answer (score 1):

You should copy the contents of `MySampleApp/app/src/main/java/com/amazonaws` verbatim into your new project and Also parts of AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle and Application.java.

For a complete instruction, I would recommend that you go through Mobile Hub Console > Project Name > Build > Select Android > On Left side go to develop > Use as an Example.

You will find all the instructions you need for your android project

Comment: I still don't get push notifications with the first method and I can't find any Use as an Example button

Answer (score 0):

The "PushListenerService" class is basically a useful example class where the magic happens. So keep every file that support that class. The

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, final String message)
```

is  what displays the notification message.

Another important note is how to get the user's device endpoint value. This can be gotten using the "PushManager" class.

```
String endpoint = pushManager.getEndpointArn();
```

The endpoint ARN of a device help you send direct notification to that device.

```
PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
publishRequest.setMessage(message);
publishRequest.setSubject(subject);
publishRequest.withTargetArn(endpoint); //This can also be a "topic" ARN
snsClient.publish(publishRequest);
```

Pretty nice job done by the guys at AWS. Big thanks to them! :D

There is no easy way out. Just take your time and go through all the code in the classes that relate to the AWS service you want to implement. Good luck!

Btw, make sure your app is not open on the test device when you send a notification to it or else you won't see a notification since your app is already running. I notice this is a default behaviour.